# align elements to the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap. Here is my code:

```
<div class="control-label">
    We
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
            <span>search</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    Something
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3j7QP/

How can I make the texts and the button appear in one line aligned to the left using thw twitter bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Classes only

#### Btn toolbar

If you want to stick strictly to classes, you can try `.btn-toolbar` but you won't have the vertical alignment.

[Demo btn-toolbar](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3j7QP/3/)

```html
<div class="control-label btn-toolbar">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

#### Floating

Floating doesn't seem to be an appropriate solution because you loose the line continuity. So you shouldn't use `.pull-left`.

### CSS

Otherwise there are several solutions :

#### No btn-group

First of all you could remove the `div.btn-group` since apparently you are not using it.

[Demo no div](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3j7QP/1/)

#### Inline blocks

Or you could use `display: inline-block;` on all elements (but you should enclose text in blocks).

[Demo inline blocks](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3j7QP/2/)

```css
.myClass > div {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-label myClass">
    <div>We</div>
    <div class="btn-group"><!-- ... --></div>
    <div>Something</div>
</div>
```